# Counting the number of integral length squares

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If $(x_i,y_j)$ are defined for $i,j\in(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...15)$ such that $x_i=i$ and $y_j=j$.

What is the probability that chosen square from the following grid has integral side length?

**My go:**

The language is mere gibberish explaining we have a 15x15 grid consisting of all the integral points.

Squares having integral sidelengths cannot lie along diagonals so there number is $15^2$`(with length 1)`+$14^2$`(with length 2)`$......1^2$`(with length 15)` But I feel I am missing counts.

```
What am I missing and how to count the total number of squares?
```

Answer (score 1):

You handled those squares whose sides lie on the grid lines correctly.

What other squares can be formed?

Clearly, the sides of the square must be congruent and perpendicular.  For squares whose sides do not lie on the grid lines, if a given side has slope $a/b$, the adjacent side must have slope $-b/a$.  In such a square, the leftmost point must be $|a| + |b|$ units to the left of the rightmost point and the bottom of the square must be $|a| + |b|$ units below the top of the square.  Also, we require that $|a| + |b| \leq 15$.

[image: squares_whose_sides_do_not_lie_on_the_grid_lines]

Which squares that do not lie on the grid lines have integer side lengths?

Squares not parallel to the grid lines can be formed if the side length of the square is the largest element in a Pythagorean triple.  For instance, a square of side length $5$ whose sides have slopes $3/4$ and $-4/3$ or $-3/4$ and $4/3$ can be placed on the grid so that its vertices have integral coordinates.  We can also have squares of side lengths $10$ and $15$.

[image: squares_with_integer_side_lengths_whose_sides_do_not_lie_on_the_grid_lines]

Any primitive Pythagorean triple ($\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$) has the form $(m^2 - n^2, 2mn, m^2 + n^2)$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers of opposite parity (one is even and the other is odd) and $m > n$.  Any other Pythagorean triple is a positive integral multiple of a Pythagorean triple.  The first few primitive Pythagorean triples are $(3, 4, 5)$, $(5, 12, 13)$, $(15, 8, 17)$, and $(7, 24, 25)$.  The condition that $|a| + |b| \leq 15$ means that the only primitive Pythagorean triple we can use is $(3, 4, 5)$.  Its multiples $(6, 8, 10)$, and $(9, 12, 15)$ also fit within the grid.